# Why is TreeSet giving classcast exception

Tags: java, collections, treeset

class student
I have made a class student that accepts roll number, standard, firstname and last name. I use TreeSet to enter the values in student. I am getting class cast exception on this program when executed. Is it because i am entering heterogeneus values that the Treeset cannot sort.

```
public class Student {

private int rollno;
private int std;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;


//getters , setters, constructors, toString

@Override
public int hashCode(){

     return Objects.hash(rollno, std, firstname,lastname);

}
}
```

class StudentTest that has Main()

```
    public class StudentTreeSet {

    public static void main(String[]args){

    Set<Student> students = new TreeSet<Student>();

    Student s1 = new Student(1,2,"Shelly","Bhargav");
    Student s2 = new Student(1,2,"Shelly","Bhargav");
    Student s3 = new Student(3,2,"Shelly","Bhargav");

    students.add(s1);
    students.add(s2);
    students.add(s3);

    students.add(s1);
    students.add(s2);
    students.add(s3);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    int studentsize2 = students.size();
    System.out.println("Again Students size ="+ studentsize2);

    for(Student student : students){
        System.out.println(student);
        System.out.println("student hashcode="+student.hashCode());
    }
   }


    }
```

output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.techlabs.studenthashset.Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
at com.techlabs.TreeSet.StudentTreeSet.main(StudentTreeSet.java:18)
```

Comment: Show us he Exception you get. I would speculate ha you get it because your `˙Student` class does not implement `Comparable` which would be needed by `TreeSet`. (Or a `Comparator` specified in instantiation...)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `Comparable<>` interface for the `Student` class. Tree set internally make use of comparable as well.

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {    
    private int rollno;
    private int std;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        if (this.rollno > o.rollno) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.rollno == o.rollno) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better implementation would be simply `return Integer.compare(this.rollno, o.rollno);`

Comment: @ Aditya  why are we using Comparable<student> what does it do

Comment: @Java_Learner : TreeSet : A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used. 

For more details refer to official documentation of [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

You can go through below [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-treeset) to get more understanding.
The use of Comparable provides a way of ordering to TreeSet api. This is necessary for user defined objects.

Answer (score 0):

1.TreeSet is a sorted set,if the value you add to the treeSet can't be compared to each other,treeSet will throw ClassCastException.
2. The Student class is not comparable,how do you expect the TreeSet sorted for you.Maybe what you need is org.apache.commons.collections.set.ListOrderedSet.

[TreeMap.put method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

As per the oracle document 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

**public TreeSet()**

Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements inserted into the set must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set. If the user attempts to add an element to the set that violates this constraint (for example, the user attempts to add a string element to a set whose elements are integers), the add call will throw a ClassCastException.